# Are there any sustained efforts to model existing ecosystems?

Tags: computational-model, ecosystem

Are there any ongoing, sustained efforts to obtain enough data about an ecosystem or part of one to build a viable computer simulation of it? All I can find (e.g. [in Brazil](https://www.unicamp.br/fea/ortega/java/index.htm) or by [google](https://sites.google.com/site/ecosimgroup/research/ecosystem-simulation)) appear to be sandboxes for demonstration or experimental purposes.

What I envision is a true model that can predict the future development of an existing system, and of course run simulations to predict the impact of certain external changes: Deforestation, temperature and precipitation patterns, introduction of non-native species etc.

Such a model would require a fairly detailed and complete biological inventory as well as detailed knowledge of the species' interactions, and a detailed map of the physical and chemical makeup of the location or region (water, ground, atmosphere, radiation). This would obviously be a vast undertaking, but with the potential of tremendous insights. Last not least, such a model would be a tremendous planning tool.

Are there any projects attempting this?

Comment: https://madingley.github.io/about/

Comment: The two hyperlinks both point to the same page. Is this a mistake?

Comment: @acvill Thanks for the observation. Fixed. (The google program, which is freely available [at github](https://github.com/EcoSimIBM), looks like a lot of fun.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Such a model would require a fairly detailed and complete biological inventory as well as detailed knowledge of the species' interactions, and a detailed map of the physical and chemical makeup of the location or region...

I suggest reading about the The Simons Collaboration on Computational Biogeochemical Modeling of Marine Ecosystems (CBIOMES).<sup>**1**</sup> This collaboration has produced ample research concerning the modeling of marine microbial communities in terms of spatial composition, metabolic interactions, nutrient flow, and seasonal variation.

Here are the research efforts highlighted on their website:

> **Developing New Computational Modeling Frameworks**
>
> - [Developing a New Trait-based Understanding of Microbial Communities Based on Metabolic and Elemental and Macromolecular Constraints](https://cbiomes.org/research/developing-a-new-trait-based-understanding-of-microbial-communities/) (led by Zoe Finkel/Dal)
> - [Constraint-based Modeling of Marine Microbial Community Metabolism and Physiology](https://cbiomes.org/research/constraint-based-modeling-of-marine-microbial-community-metabolism-and-physiology/) (led by John Casey/MIT)
> - [Statistical Modeling of Microbial Communities: Niches, Traits, and Interactions](https://cbiomes.org/research/statistical-modeling-of-microbial-communities-niches-traits-and-interactions/) (led by Andrew Irwin/Dal)
> - [Thermodynamically Constrained Metabolic Networks for Ocean Modeling](https://cbiomes.org/research/thermodynamically-constrained-metabolic-networks-for-ocean-modeling/) (led by Joe Vallino/MBL)
> - [Models of Marine Microbial Biogeography and Biogeochemistry](https://cbiomes.org/research/models-of-marine-microbial-biogeography-and-biogeochemistry/) (led by Mick Follows and Stephanie Dutkiewicz/MIT)
>
> **Collecting and Compiling Relevant Datasets**
>
> - [Ocean Color and Biogeochemistry](https://cbiomes.org/research/ocean-color-and-ocean-biogeochemistry/) (led by Shubha Sathyendranath/PML)
> - [Data and Tools to Define the Biogeography of Marine Microbes](https://cbiomes.org/research/data-and-tools-to-define-the-biogeography-of-marine-microbes/) (led by Ginger Armbrust/UW)
> - [Microbial Growth, Interactions and Biogeographies from ‘Omics’ Data](https://cbiomes.org/research/microbial-growth-interactions-and-biogeographies-from-omics-data/) (led by Jed Fuhrman/USC)
>
> **Bringing Together Models with Data**
>
> - [Advanced Statistical Analysis of Marine Microbial Systems](https://cbiomes.org/research/advanced-statistical-analysis-of-marine-microbial-systems/) (led by Christian Müller/Flatiron Institute)
> - [Unifying Data and Models through Biogeography](https://cbiomes.org/research/unifying-data-and-models-through-biogeography/) (led by Chris Follett/MIT)
> - [Data Assimilative Modeling of Marine Ecosystems](https://cbiomes.org/research/data-assimilative-modeling-of-marine-ecosystems/) (led by Chris Edwards/UCSC)
> - [Statistical Network Inference and Time Series Analysis](https://cbiomes.org/research/statistical-network-inference-and-time-series-analysis-of-marine-ecosystems/) (led by Jacob Bien/USC)

Concerning specific geographic sites, one of the best understood marine ecosystems is the San Pedro Channel off the coast of Los Angeles, which has been studied since 1998 as part of the SPOT project.<sup>**2**</sup> Sampling efforts from this site include sensors that capture continuous *in situ* measurements of dissolved oxygen, fluorescence, temperature, salinity, and pressure, as well as monthly charters that collect seawater to measure nutrients (nitrate, nitrite, phosphate, silicate) and chlorophyll at 12 discrete water column depths. Peruse the [publications section](https://dornsife.usc.edu/spot/publications/) of the SPOT website to better understand the ecological and geochemical research that the SPOT project has enabled.

If you are further interested in the global effort to characterize and model the dynamics of marine microbial communities, I recommend a 2015 review by Fuhrman, Cram, and Needham<sup>**3**</sup>, which discusses methods to analyze microbial networks through space and time.

---

**References**

1. https://cbiomes.org/
2. https://dornsife.usc.edu/spot/
3. Fuhrman JA, Cram JA, Needham DM. Marine microbial community dynamics and their ecological interpretation. *Nat Rev Microbiol*. 2015 Mar;13(3):133-46.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you define "model an ecosystem" the answer is somewhere on the spectrum from "yes, it's routine" to "no, that's impossible."

Let's start with the positive side. Ecosystem modeling based on inventories of species, information about their interactions, and spatial and environmental context are routinely used for analysis, prediction, and recommendation. For example, [the Ecopath software tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecopath), developed for modeling marine fisheries, appears to have been in pragmatic use for three decades by a wide community involving many different categories of stakeholders.

Now to the negative side. There is an inherent issue of scale and stochasticity in any question of ecosystems, not to mention their entanglement with scale-free and chaotic processes. Indeed, two of the prime examples of inherent unpredictability due to chaotic dynamics are [population growth versus ecological limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) and [weather prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Norton_Lorenz#Chaos_theory). That doesn't mean we can't learn quite a lot about a system, though, as chaotic systems still operate within [regions of the model space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Strange_attractor) that can often be well-characterized and have high predictive value.

So, what to make of these apparently contradictory positions?
The takeaways that I would recommend are:

1. Ecosystems can be and are modeled effectively, but the models must be carefully formulated with respect to the questions that are being asked.
2. In modeling an ecosystem, more detail is not necessarily better, as the wrong type of detail can ruin the predictive power of a model.